# Return number of rows doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

This is the code I currently have:

```
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM Account WHERE accountKey=? AND accountUsername=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $key,$username);

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $numrows = $stmt->num_rows;
```

The problem is the query is fine. I tryed it on PHPMyAdmin and it return me one result. When I check how many result I got with this one is always 0 when it should be 1... Do you know what could happen...

Query from PHPMyAdmin:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsVyS.png

Comment: So what is `?` ? Also note you are using `prepare`.

Comment: The query is fine. I don't get any error. It just return 0 I tried to only put accountKey or accountUsername and none of them was changing anything...

Comment: Maybe I should be more direct. In to say what is `$key` and `$username`. And does it exists in `Account`?

Comment: I've never used `store_result`, but the man page says that it transfers the result set from the last query. Is it perhaps emptying the result set before you get chance to use it? What do you get if you move the `num_rows` call to before you call `store_result`?

Comment: If you're not checking for errors, do.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and for example `if(!$result = $mysqli->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $mysqli->error . ']');
}`

Comment: If you know how to read the logs [`dump_debug_info`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.dump-debug-info.php) might be useful.

Comment: I don't get any error and I did that: 

function test($key){
    include("../script/connection.php");
    $mysqli = new mysqli($SQLhost, $SQLusername, $SQLpassword, $SQLdatabase);
    if(!$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Account WHERE accountKey='$key'")){
        die('There was an error running the query [' . $mysqli->error . ']');
    }else{
        echo("it work!");
    }
}

and it work...

Comment: Well, now you have error display for a new piece of code :) But wouldn't it be nice to get $mysqli->error for your prepared query, too?

Comment: I did that:

    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $numrows = $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->store_result();

    echo "Result: " . $result . "<br>";

and I got 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

include("../script/connection.php"); 

$link = mysqli_connect($SQLhost, $SQLusername, $SQLpassword, $SQLdatabase);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$key = '4dc5f0ea67ca3791614b28c310cd1c79';
$username = 'jean8mathieu';

$query = "SELECT * FROM Account WHERE accountKey=? AND accountUsername=?";

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query)) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $key, $username);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
    printf("Number of rows: %d.\n", mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt));
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
} else {
   printf('errno: %d, error: %s', $mysqli->errno, $mysqli->error);
   exit;
}

mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: And? Explanation would be nice. A block of code may not be clear to the OP that they are doing anything wrong. Or what they did wrong.

Comment: I get this now: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, string given in

Comment: yes, my fault, i forgot to add the $stmt as first parameter.

Comment: Again, what is `$key` and `$username`? @Jean-Mathieu

Comment: Hmm. The only things i could imagine are $key and $username not properly set or prior $stmt unclosed.

Comment: key=4dc5f0ea67ca3791614b28c310cd1c79 & user=jean8mthieu and as you can see in this image should be true: http://i.imgur.com/PFrXNgf.png

Comment: Noticed the typo in the username? "jean8mthieu" -> "jean8mathieu"